# Regex to fetch string after character and before word

Tags: regex

I'm trying to code a regex to fetch a portion of a string that is between a character and a word.

E.g.

FIRST/SECOND/999999/MATCH EVERYTHING HERE BEFORE third

It should fetch the word between "999999/" (this section will always be numeric, 6 digit, and end with a forward slash) and "third" (this word does not change).
Expected result: MATCH EVERYTHING HERE BEFORE

I ended up with the following Regex, but it only fetches the word if there's a whitespace before the word 'MATCH':

/(?<=/\s).*(?=\sthird)/

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Edit: updated for clarification. Thanks @JvdV

Comment: Would it always be a six digit section in front?

Comment: Yep! 6 digit and forward slash. Thanks

Comment: The positive lookbehind is requiring there to be whitespace before the match. Remove it and replace the `.` (matches every character) with `[^/]` (matches every character except `/`). If you absolutely need it to start with `/`, still replace the `.` as mentioned but keep the lookbehind and just remove `\s` from it.

Comment: Maybe try `(?:^|\/)\d{6}\/([^\/]+?)\s*\bthird` and use the content from 1st capture group.

Comment: Yep, that was it! Amazing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the following should work:

```
(?:^|\/)\d{6}\/([^\/]+?)\s*\bthird
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/muYnOV/1)

---

- `(?:^|\/)` - Non-capture group for start-line anchor or forward slash;
- `\/` - A literal forward slash;
- `([^\/]+?)` - Capture group to catch 1+ (lazy) characters other than forward slash;
- `\s*\bthird` - 0+ Whitespace characters, a word-boundary and literally the word third.